# How to add a "selected" class to a selected tab anchor using jQuery UI Tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-tabs

I'm using jQuery UI tabs(). It adds "ui-tabs-selected" to the selected LI, but each LI has an ID because it's different. Due to the multi ID/class bug in IE6, I need to apply a "selected" class to the anchor that is inside the "ui-tabs-selected" LI.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do

```
$('li.ui-tabs-selected a').addClass('yourclass');
```

To manually add a class to any of the tabs you can do assuming your `ul` has the id `#tabs`

```
$('#tabs li a').eq(1).addClass('yourclass'); //this will add class to second tab
```

**Updated Answer**
Use the select event to trigger `addClass()`

```
$('#wrap').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).find('li a').removeClass('myclass').eq(ui.index).addClass('myclass')
    }
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/6JryL/

Comment: Nothing seems to be happening. Wouldn't this need to be added in an Event Listener in order for the class to be applied?

Comment: @Cofey, Yes you need to use the select event to trigger addClass. Check updated answer with working jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.ui-tabs-selected a').addClass('selected');
```